# PHP included script execute as if it was in caller script's directory

Tags: php, include

I have a site which has a tree as follow:

```
public_html/
    index.php
    lang.fr.php
    lang.en.php
    lang.php
    description/
        index.php
        lang.fr.php
        lang.en.php
 ... (lots of directory basically like description)
```

All `index.php` include `lang.php`, which is supposed to include each pages' version of `lang.fr.php` or `lang.en.php`. However, if I simply put

```
include("lang.{$lang}.php");
```

it includes the `lang.fr.php` of the `lang.php`'s directory.

Is it possible or do I have to put `lang.php`'s content in each pages?

Comment: i think: `include(__DIR__."lang.{$lang}.php");`

Comment: No, since `__DIR__` returns the script (`lang.php`) directory.
"If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned." => Magic constants section of the manual

Comment: you can write `__DIR__` to a variable to use before the include and use that variable

Comment: @Dagon Brillant! Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign `__DIR__` to a variable before the include, and use that variable to include the appropriate language file

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that include() is simply doing what it is suppose to, which is include files from it's configured include_path.

You can actually update the include path in your PHP Configuration file, or better yet, update the include_path ONLY for the duration of the script, if that is your desire, using the set_include_path() function. The simplest solution would be simply typing the entire path in include().

Here is some documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php